# Chrome (and ONLY Chrome) Suddenly Can't Connect to Localhost Domains

Tags: apache, google-chrome, dns, vagrant

Well this is odd. As of this morning, Chrome is responding with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when it attempts to connect to web pages at various `{subdomain}.localhost` domains. Firefox and Safari both connect as normal. I am using Vagrant/Virtualbox running Debian and Apache. Chrome does connect to local domains which ARE NOT using `localhost` in the domain name. Wondering if chrome released some sort of local firewall?? But not seeing anything about that in release notes.

**UPDATE**: running `curl {subdomain}.localhost` in terminal gives me the output as expected (response from web server).

**UPDATE 2**: I did just find this: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9210484 (Chrome team planning to block all access from browser to localhost wss) -- but I do not see that this was implemented yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in my second update. No more `.localhost`.

Comment: This does not explain what I'm seeing at all, as I can connect to localhost on some ports, but not others.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the port explicitly -> xxx.localhost:8080

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11326623)

Comment: he has a problem to connect from his host. In Vagrant you use port 8080 to connect to your guest machines http. So it is possible to open his page in chrome if he use {subdomain}.localhost:8080 instead of {subdomain}.localhost